# Possible to define outlook 2003 email signature template?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

I need to define an email signature for everyone in the company to use.  Is there a way to define some kind of template to send to everyone (so they can easily install it), or am I stuck with giving them instructions to copy & paste one and set it up themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution might be adding a template stored on a network shared or something so users can edit the signature and add it to Outlook manually.

The signature is stored in C:\Documents and Settings\%Username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook
and I believe, but not certain, it's in the file: Outlook.NK2
In any case it is not readily editable.

You can also put that template in that folder above but this should not be accurate.

Definitely, I would just give them the template and let them add their info and let them know how to add it in Outlook.

Hope this help!